# Changing Symfony Default Route Class

Tags: routes, symfony1, symfony-1.4, yaml

In symfony's routing.yml, you can assign a different class to be used in place of sfRoute.
i.e.

```
routeName:
 url: /url/blah
 class: sfRequestRoute
 param: {module: mymod, action: myaction}
 requirements:
   sf_method: [get]
```

However, I would like to be able to change the default class so that all routes use sfRequestRoute unless I specify otherwise.  Is there a way to do this?  I am using Symfony 1.4

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not exactly in the way you want. Something like that were it available would be found in `config/factories.yml`. But in this case the default is hardcoded into `sfRoutingConfigHandler`. You could attempt to override that but it seems liek a lot of work for a simple nicety. Instead i would jsut use a YAML reference:

```
routeName:
 url: /url/blah
 class: &defRouteClass 'sfRequestRoute'
 param: {module: mymod, action: myaction}
 requirements:
   sf_method: [get]

anotherRouteName:
  url: /url/blah2
  class: *defRouteClass
  param: {module: mymod, action: myotheraction}
```

Comment: It's not ideal, but as you mentioned, an ideal solution is probably not available without modifying sfRoutingConfigHandler.   Thanks for the tip on YAML references; I wasn't aware that could be done.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can.
You should change a routing.yml in your application.
[Symfony factories.yml](http://www.symfony-project.org/reference/1_4/en/05-Factories#chapter_05_routing)

for example:

```
all:
  routing:
    class: sfRequestRoute
```

I tested, it works fine

Comment: Thats odd... that should be for the Routing class, not the Route class, ie a subclass of `sfRouting` not `sfRoute`.

Comment: When I tried it I got Argument 2 passed to sfRoute::__construct() must be an array, null given, called in /somefolder/symfony-1.4.11/lib/routing/sfRequestRoute.class.php

Comment: Oh...at first I did not understand what you mean, but now realized